# What is the best algorithm to find the lowest of N number just by using 2 variables in Python 2?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am new to Python. And I just wrote a simple function to find the largest of the entered numbers by just using 2 variables.

```
def find_greatest():
    m = 0
    while(True):
        n = raw_input('Enter number: ')
        n = float(n)
        if (n>=m):
            m = n
            greatest = n
        elif (n==-1):
            print('Greatest number is ' + str(greatest))
            break
```

I do not want to use lists or dictionaries. Now what i want is just to use 2 variables to find the lowest of the numbers by making some changes in the above code.

Comment: You have code that finds the largest, and you want to change it to find the smallest; what do you think you might need to change?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Simply the condition i.e. ((n<=m)) i believe. I did that but could not get it right.

Comment: Could you correctly indent your code so we can easily read it?

Comment: @s16h Sure! Just indented the code for you.

Comment: [to change code for a function printing the largest of the numbers entered, I need to change] `Simply the condition i.e. ((n<=m))` you forget to keep the name of the function telling. And to present the result of your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
def foo():
    m = 0
    n = 0
    Input = raw_input('Enter numbers:\n')
    numbers = Input.split(",")
    n, m = float(numbers[0]), float(numbers[1])
    if n > m:
        return n
    elif m > n:
        return m
    else m == n:
        print "Numbers are equal\n"
```

more clear code.
So, for lowest number you need just reverse comparison operators

Answer (score 0):

This is generally not a great way of doing what you want to do but the reason why simply changing `n >= m` to `n <= m` won't work is because the `n == -1` check needs to be the first check in the `if` statement.

If you insist to do it this way, try something like this:

```
def find_smallest():
    smallest = None
    while(True):
        n = raw_input('Enter number: ')
        try:
            n = float(n)
        except ValueError:
            print 'Enter a valid positive number.'
            continue

        if (n == -1.0):
            if smallest is None:
                print('Cannot find smallest. No numbers were entered.')
            else:
                print('Smallest number is {}'.format(smallest))
                break

        if n < 0:
            print('Enter a positive number.')
            continue
        else:
            smallest = n
```